# NetGrab UserContol Karl E. Peterson

Tags: vb6

Does anyone know where I can get a copy of this package? At one time it was downloadable from his website but sadly, no more.

NetGrab UserControl, asynchronous download code/package is no longer freely downloadable from his website or from anywhere it seems.

Comment: I'm very rusty on using VB6 nowadays, but there's an old discussion about that control [here](https://microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion.narkive.com/UqqAjfk3/download-file-from-https) which includes a [link](http://vbnet.mvps.org/code/internet/urldownloadtofilenocache.htm) to some code from Randy Birch that apparently does the same thing as the control.

Comment: Is it not available on Karl's site?   https://classicvb.net/samples/NetGrab  ?

Comment: John E., Thanks for the links! MarkL, Thanks but the download doesn't work from there. I've found a few other promising leads in the links above.

Comment: @MarkL The article is available but the download link for the control just points straight back to the article. :^(

Comment: @JohnEason, I think that link is encountering a 500, but it's not getting displayed (not sure why).  OP could try the wayback machine.  Or there is a pdf article on that page that describes the control code, seems to probably have at least most of the code in text in the pdf?  Could try to build-your-own with that.

Comment: Thanks, MarkL. That's a great idea. The page was there (2016) but the download wasn't available from the old page. My surmise is that it was removed from the website before 2016. No worries. Looks like other avenues will pan out.